# Filter table column in a table view

Tags: javafx, tableview

Is there a way to filter table columns data as there is a way in excel to filter.
Filtering manually require a very long code if data is huge. So trying to find an easy way. Please suggest something.
I went through the following link for the same but need an easier and efficient approach.
http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/

Comment: The link you gave is the easiest and most efficient way I could think of for implementing what you want. What's your problem with it?

Comment: If I have thousand rows with different data and I want to view just few then this process seems to be tedious to me. I want exactly the same feature of filtering as provided by microsoft excel.

Comment: Why can't you use the methods in that link to create a filter similar to the one in Excel? You probably need to create and post a [simple example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show what you have tried.

Comment: Actually what i need to ask that is there a direct way inbuilt in javafx like there is tablemenubutton, sorting functions. Similarly in javafx, in there any inbuilt  functionality for filtering?

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in filter capability for TableViews like Excel.

I've written a library that provides the GUI filters, but you'll still need to programmatically apply the results to filter your dataset:

<s>https://code.google.com/p/javafx-filterable-table-columns/</s>

https://github.com/jhsheets/javafx-filterable-table-columns

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an extension for that use case:

https://github.com/maimArt/TableFilterFX

The implementation of the filter is quite easy. You wrap your TableView with the TableFilter and add the columns that should be filterd by tableFilter.filterColumn(TableColumn column)

1 Build your TableView like usual by code or fxml

```
TableView<Pojo> table = new TableView<>();
table.getItems().addAll(pojoList);
TableColumn<Pojo, String> columnA = new TableColumn<>("ColA");
TableColumn<Pojo, String> columnB = new TableColumn<>("ColB");
table.getColumns().add(columnA);
table.getColumns().add(columnB);
```

2 After that apply the filter

```
TableFilter<Pojo> tableFilter = new TableFilter<>(table);
tableFilter.filterColumn(columnA);
tableFilter.filterColumn(columnB);
```

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: Looks better now, thanks. (Not my downvote btw, I lack domain knowledge to vote on this.)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Hope the downvoter can also give me some feedback to improve my behaviour or code.